# Kafka Consumption in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, apache-kafka

I'd like to visualize a Kafka stream using Unity3D. What's the best way to get access to the data stream in Unity?

I have written basic consumers in Node and C#, but I'm not sure how to incorporate them into Unity. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for, but a "basic consumer" should be no differerent when using any external framework

Comment: Well, I found this package: https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet but I'm not sure how to get it to work within Unity.

Comment: I've not used C# in years, but yes that library is recommended, maintained, and enterprise supported by Confluent, and how do you get other Nuget libraries into your project?

Comment: I have no idea, I'm new to Unity, hence why I ask :D

Comment: Well, I guess that's why you have a few close votes as too-broad. But the simple answer to "how to install (x) in C#" is "use NuGet", which is built into Visual Studio, https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/features/game-development/#tab-4b0d0be8de5f65564ad

Comment: Hi did anyone find the solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54703187/kafka-integration-in-unity3d-throwing-win32exception-error

Answer (score 1):

I dont come with a complete solution, because I'am working on the problem currently. The main problem I encountered with unity3D is to execute things in a separate thread, separate from the game loop which is a thread itself. I you succeed to execute code outside of the game loop and then pass data between your thread and the main loop you are done. and You then should use https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet

There is another problem, unity want manage every thing with the lib and it conflict with visual studio lib versions and with nugget. So you have to find a workflow to counter that. If you go full  visual studio you will loose the unity interface simplicity. In general you import your lib and then unity mess it.

Comment: Did you find the solution of unity3d and kafka integration? Can you post the complete answer

Comment: Were you able to get this working? Do you have any additional info?

Comment: nop because abandonned the whole project, but what you want to do is to find a way to execute your code in a separate thread from the main game loop