# Unity + Confluent's Apache Kafka .NET client?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, apache-kafka

I'd like to map a kafka stream to Unity inputs.

I was able to get an output to console in C# Using [this example](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/examples/Consumer/Program.cs) from https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet.

But I'm not sure how to import this package into Unity.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/54703187/7111561

Answer (score 0):

You can add  [Confluent nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Confluent.Kafka/) to you solution, copy the dll's (Confluent.Kafka and librdkafka) to the Assets/Plugins folder of your Unity project.

I have managed to make it work in Unity application build on Windows, but unfortunately could not make it work on Android.