# DllNotFoundException in Kafka Unity3d on Mac

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I'm having trouble using Kafka in unity3d on mac.

I followed the steps in the solution to get Kafka in Unity3D: [Kafka integration in unity3d throwing Win32Exception error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54703187/kafka-integration-in-unity3d-throwing-win32exception-error)

And when I try to setup a consumer, I get the following error:

```
DllNotFoundException: kernel32
Confluent.Kafka.Impl.Librdkafka.Initialize (System.String userSpecifiedPath) (at /Users/user/Desktop/confluent-kafka-dotnet-1.1.0/src/Confluent.Kafka/Impl/LibRdKafka.cs:376)
Confluent.Kafka.Consumer`2[TKey,TValue]..ctor (Confluent.Kafka.ConsumerBuilder`2[TKey,TValue] builder) (at /Users/user/Desktop/confluent-kafka-dotnet-1.1.0/src/Confluent.Kafka/Consumer.cs:537)
Confluent.Kafka.ConsumerBuilder`2[TKey,TValue].Build () (at /Users/user/Desktop/confluent-kafka-dotnet-1.1.0/src/Confluent.Kafka/ConsumerBuilder.cs:360)
KafkaConsumer.RunConsume (System.String brokerList, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] topics, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) (at Assets/KafkaConsumer.cs:43)
KafkaConsumer.StartConsume () (at Assets/KafkaConsumer.cs:19)
KafkaConsumer.Start () (at Assets/KafkaConsumer.cs:13)
```

I have tried building the .dll files in visual studio community 2019, copying the .dlls from the bin. I also unzipped the nuget package, and tried those .dlls as well.

I have tried both versions 1.1.0 and 1.2.0.

I also printed the path of the Librdkafka.dll right before it failed to load, and the path was correct.

Here is my consumer code:

```
ConsumerConfig config = new ConsumerConfig
        {
            BootstrapServers = brokerList,
            GroupId = "csharp-consumer",
            EnableAutoCommit = false,
            StatisticsIntervalMs = 5000,
            SessionTimeoutMs = 6000,
            AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest,
            EnablePartitionEof = true
        };
        const int commitPeriod = 5;
        using (var consumer = new ConsumerBuilder<Ignore, string>(config)
            // Note: All handlers are called on the main .Consume thread.
            .SetErrorHandler((_, e) => Console.WriteLine($"Error: {e.Reason}"))
            .SetStatisticsHandler((_, json) => Console.WriteLine($"Statistics: {json}"))
            .SetPartitionsAssignedHandler((c, partitions) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Assigned partitions: [{string.Join(", ", partitions)}]");
                    // possibly manually specify start offsets or override the partition assignment provided by
                    // the consumer group by returning a list of topic/partition/offsets to assign to, e.g.:
                    // 
                    // return partitions.Select(tp => new TopicPartitionOffset(tp, externalOffsets[tp]));
                })
            .SetPartitionsRevokedHandler((c, partitions) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Revoking assignment: [{string.Join(", ", partitions)}]");
            })
            .Build())
        {
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You did copy all the dlls as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57881634/7111561)? In general if those DLL are not compiled for Mac but windows then they won't work on Mac.... In Unity on each dll you can/have to also configure for which platform(s) they shall be used.

Comment: I couldn't find libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll, do you know where i could get those?